# C# TableAdapter Fills in with DateTime Field. how do i edit so only Time is shown in the table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime, tableadapter

My windows form project displays a table using the TableAdapter with the following Columns: Name, Location, Start Time, Category. The Start Time column corresponds to a DateTime field in the MS Visual Studio 2010 Dataset. It is redundant in the table to display MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM when the label above the table displays "Events for MM/DD/YYY". How can I display just the Time in the Table? The table automatically populates with the information and there is no way for me to say date.ToShortTimeString() before the info enters the table.

Comment: as a datagrid (the name of the table is datagridview1)

Answer (score 3):

Set the format for the column to `t`.
For specific instructions, see the documentation for your grid control (or whatever you're using).

**EDIT**: In .Net's built-in DataGridView, you can set the column's [`DefaultCellStyle.Format` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) to `"t"`.

For more information, see [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Comment: this.dataGridView1.Columns["Start Time"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t"; keeps giving a null pointer exception. in the dataset it is stored as startTime. the header text is "Start Time"

Comment: @doubledian, use the column's *name*, not the header text

Comment: using the designer i set the column properties to just Month to see if it would work. it instead still showed the default DateTime...